# rotation_euler is not applied to the object

Tags: python, transforms

After the simulation, the "rotation_euler" of target object is :

```
Euler((1.268485188484192, 2.9926466941833496, -0.3283208906650543), 'XYZ')
```

however the "matrix_world" is not:

```
Matrix(

    ((0.30000001192092896, 0.0, 0.0, 6.445583343505859),
    (0.0, 0.30000001192092896, 0.0, -2.347369909286499),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.30000001192092896, 0.7437435388565063),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

it only contains its translation and scaling.
BTW, this situation only appears when the target object is the result of bpy.ops.object.join().

the related code is shown as below:

```
def _load_gltf(self, filepath):
   if os.path.exists(filepath):
        # previously_selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
        bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=filepath)
        objs       = bpy.context.selected_objects
        obj_joined = self._join_objs(objs)
        return obj_joined, tri_joined

def _join_objs(self, list_objs):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    for obj in list_objs:
        bpy.data.objects[obj.name].select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.join()
    obj_joined = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    return MeshObject(obj_joined)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your object doesn't have the right rotation mode.

It is not documented but you need to set the [rotation_mode](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_mode) attribute to `"XYZ"` before appyling the `rotation_euler` otherwise the change is not registered in the actual object matrix.

```
previous_mode = obj.rotation_mode 
obj.rotation_mode = "XYZ"
obj.rotation_euler = (1.268485188484192, 2.9926466941833496, -0.3283208906650543)
obj.rotation_mode  = previous_mode
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this tackled my problem exactly! When .gftl file is loaded, its rotation_mode is "quaternions" in default.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much again! Recently I have met a new problem "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253554/wrong-rendering-result", hoping that you can give me a hand!