# Wrong rendering result

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normals

I try to render the objects of ShapeNet, however, when in "material preview mode", it looks right, when it turns to the "render preview mode", the result looks strange.

[image: material preview mode]

"Material preview mode"

[image: render preview mode]

"Render preview mode"

I thought it might be caused by the wrong normals, so I visualized the normals, and find that there are two normals per face(eg, the face in the color "brown".

[image: the normals outside the object]

"The normals outside the object"

[image: the normals inside the object]

"The normals inside the object"

[image]

Comment: Looks like Z-fight ... your normals screens confirm model is double sided ... probably too close to each other for blender ... delete inner faces (selection could work with "L" key linked. (written before you shared a file)

Comment: As vklidu says, some faces are overlapping, you need to in Edit mode, put your mouse over the mesh, press L to select and move with G, delete the part you don't want

Comment: That's right! However, do you know how can I operate in python?

Comment: in this specific case its easier to just Merge by Distance and Recalculate Normals (outside) (Warning you will lose UV map)

Comment: Any other solution? Even if it is complicated. And I wonder the reason why it looks good when it is turned to the material preview mode but becomes bad when it is turned to the render preview mode(or when it is rendering), maybe I can solve this problem by utilizing the differences between these two kinds of mode. I really need the UV map.

Comment: Than you have to somehow select and delete all faces pointing inside.